# Are there languages without fillers like "um" or "uh"?

Tags: list-of-languages, spoken-language, particles, discourse, filler

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsMWbVrjucg&t=34s

According to this video (0:55) almost every language has those speech disfluencies. But ALMOST. Do languages exist that have no such sounds for hesitation? Languages where you just go silent when you have to think?

Comment: It’s hard to prove a negative across 6,000+ languages, but I’d wager it’s unlikely. Making a non-committal noise to indicate that you’re thinking or that there’s more speech to come seems pretty universal. I suppose languages that are inherently highly stylised, like Silbo (whistled language used for simple, long-range communication) or Damin (used for ceremonial purposes) may not have fillers, since they’re not normally used for prepared speech only, but any language used for unprepared speech will probably have them.

Comment: It is really dubious whether the languages actually have them as actual parts of those languages.

Comment: @VladimirF To some extent, true – they’re not lexical items like ‘chair’ or ‘eat’. But the actual shape of fillers is definitely determined by the speaker’s language. English, for example, would use [əː] and _like_ where Spanish would use [ɛː] and _pues_ (better equivalent?), Danish [œː] and _s’n_, Mandarin [ʌː] and 那个 _nèige_, etc. So you can’t really call them separate from the language either.

Comment: I don't know if it's the case here, but it may be that the speaker wanted to avoid making an overly strong statement that could then be proven wrong with a single counterexample, and chose to add a possibly unnecessary caveat. In text I'll often temper a claim that I believe to be universal, but don't wish to put too much strength behind that claim (and in particular, don't want the reader to assume I have more evidence than I do) by writing "(almost?) all", but that doesn't work so well in speech